# Create a user that can connect to the database in H2

Tags: h2

To create a user in H2, one does:

```
CREATE USER NEWUSER PASSWORD 'P';
```

How is it possible to create a new user that can connect to an existing database in H2?

I have tried:

```
GRANT ALL TO NEWUSER;
```

but this does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You can do as follows (see [here](https://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#create_user)):

```
create user if not exists scott password 'tiger' admin;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting user as administrator:

```
ALTER USER TOM ADMIN TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked on H2 version 2.1.210:

1. Create new user with command:

   ```
   CREATE USER newuser PASSWORD 'newpwd';
   ```
2. Log in as admin (schema owner, by default it's 'sa') and get schema name:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA;
   ```

In my case the schema name was 'PUBLIC';

3. To assign all rights to the new user, use this command:

   ```
   GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA PUBLIC TO newuser;
   ```
4. Check the result, you should see newuser with RIGHTS=ALL here:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.RIGHTS;
   ```